# Django d3.js in HTML file not loading unless I manually open HTML file

Tags: html, json, django, d3.js

I'm trying to implement a bubble chart on a webpage using the Django framework and the D3.js framework. I have an HTML file, and my data is stored in a JSON file.

Accessing the JSON file seems fine, because when I manually open the HTML file in my browser it works/loads fine, however, when I hit the webpage URL endpoint via Django, the D3 part of the page just shows blank (console says "node is undefined"). I am using the example code given [here](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4063269).

Any help would be very appreciated. Thanks.

D3 js code:

```
<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>

<div class="cloud">
<script>

var diameter = 960,
    format = d3.format(",d"),
    color = d3.scale.category20c();

var bubble = d3.layout.pack()
    .sort(null)
    .size([diameter, diameter])
    .padding(1.5);

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", diameter)
    .attr("height", diameter)
    .attr("class", "bubble");

d3.json("cloud.json", function(error, root) {
  var node = svg.selectAll(".node")
      .data(bubble.nodes(classes(root))
      .filter(function(d) { return !d.children; }))
    .enter().append("g")
      .attr("class", "node")
      .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")"; });

  node.append("title")
      .text(function(d) { return d.className + ": " + format(d.value); });

  node.append("circle")
      .attr("r", function(d) { return d.r; })
      .style("fill", function(d) { return color(d.packageName); });

  node.append("text")
      .attr("dy", ".3em")
      .style("text-anchor", "middle")
      .text(function(d) { return d.className.substring(0, d.r / 3); });
});

// Returns a flattened hierarchy containing all leaf nodes under the root.
function classes(root) {
  var classes = [];

  function recurse(name, node) {
    if (node.children) node.children.forEach(function(child) { recurse(node.name, child); });
    else classes.push({packageName: name, className: node.name, value: node.size});
  }

  recurse(null, root);
  return {children: classes};
}

d3.select(self.frameElement).style("height", diameter + "px");

</script>
```

Comment: Is you HTML file a template (called using the Django `render()` function)? If so, you probably need to place your static assets in a different directory. Typically, you put templates in the `templates/` directory and assets in the `static/` directory, though this can be configured any way you like. [Setting up static assets](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/howto/static-files/)

Comment: @JeremyBlalock would this make a difference though? Because if I open my HTML file directly, it loads the information properly.